# Spring AntRequestMatcher does not match

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, pattern-matching

I have a question about ant matchers. I want to create a spring security filter that is not applied to a certain URL.

To ignore this url I'm using `AntPathRequestMatcher`:

```
AntPathRequestMatcher ignored = new AntPathRequestMatcher("**/MyURL/**");
```

Actually I thought that it would match all the URLs that contain "MyURL". But I was wrong.

```
if(ignored.matches(httpReq)) {
    log.info(ignored.toString()+" matches "+httpReq.getRequestURI());            
} else {
    log.info(ignored.toString()+" does not match "+httpReq.getRequestURI());             
}
```

This if-section above brings me

```
Ant [pattern='**/myurl/**'] does not match /resource/MyURL/
```

in log when I make a request. The pattern [should be case unsensitive](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/AntPathRequestMatcher.html).

Comment: Which version of Spring Security are you using?

Comment: @Tunaki, I use 4.0.0. But are the rules of ant-matching not the same for all of versions?

Comment: It doesn't start with a `/` so it doesn't match

Answer (score 2):

As [@M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) wrote your pattern has to start with `/`, see [AntPathMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html):

> **Note:** a pattern and a path must both be absolute or must both be relative in order for the two to match. Therefore it is recommended that users of this implementation to sanitize patterns in order to prefix them with "/" as it makes sense in the context in which they're used.

and [AntPathMatcher#doMatch](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-core/4.1.7.RELEASE/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.java#AntPathMatcher.doMatch%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cboolean%2Cjava.util.Map%29):

```
protected boolean More ...doMatch(String pattern, String path, boolean fullMatch, Map<String, String> uriTemplateVariables) {
    if (path.startsWith(this.pathSeparator) != pattern.startsWith(this.pathSeparator)) {
        return false;
    }
```